# Evaluating a Twice Differentiable Function with a Given Integral Value

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Given $f(x)$ is a twice differentiable function on $[0,\pi]$.

If $f(\pi)=2$ and $\int_0^\pi \left[f(x)+f''(x)\right]\sin(x)dx=5$ where $f''(x)= \dfrac{d^2f}{dx^2}$ what if f(0)?

I'd like a small hint to push forward through the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Write the integral as $\int_{0}^{\pi}(f(x)+f''(x))sin(x)dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(x)dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}f''(x)\sin(x)dx$ and now perform integration by parts on both integrals.

Comment: Thank you !!!!!